# Checking input value against several values using .includes()

Tags: javascript, jquery, passwords

I have a simple form where one predefined password will show hidden div. I would like to have several valid passwords instead of just one. I have researched and maybe an array of passwords can be checked with includes() function?

this is my code for ONE password:

```
<div id="passw">
    <div>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password + Enter" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('button').click()" /> <!-- IMPORTANT! this part is so if you click enter, it works. -->
        </div>
    <div>
                                                
    <input id="button" type="hidden" value="Submit" onclick="if (document.getElementById('password').value == 'password123') { 
            document.getElementById('section-hidden').classList.toggle('show');   
            document.getElementById('passw').style.display='none';
        } else {  
            alert('Invalid Password!'); password.setSelectionRange(0, password.value.length);   
        } " />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `includes()` method and check if the entered password is included in the array.

**Simple use of `includes():`**

```js
const passwords = ["password123", "password456"];

  if (passwords.includes("password123")) {
    console.log("Good password");
  } 
  if (passwords.includes("password999")) {
    console.log("Good password");
  } 
  else { 
    console.log("Bad password!");
  }
```

So just add some `passwords` array, and change the condition of the `if` statement to this:

```
if(passwords.includes(document.getElementById('password').value))
```